# What is the work-around for deleting orphan entities using JPA 2.0 and @OneToMany?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orphaned-objects

I'm using JPA 2.0, Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE, and Java 1.6.  I have this entity with a one-to-many relationship to another entity …

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
...
@Entity
@Table(name = "classroom")
public class Classroom implements Serializable
{
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "classroom", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Set<ClassroomUser> roster;
```

However, when I update my entity with a different set of ClassroomUser objects

```
classroom.setRoster(newRoster);
```

and save the entity, all the previous ClassroomUser objects remain.  What is the proper/shortest way to update my entity while removing all the orphan records from the database?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `orphanRemoval`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="classroom", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

Whenever an entry is removed from the persistent set, it will get deleted. And this means you need to work **with the persistent set**. I.e. you are not allowed to replace the set, instead you should do:

```
classroom.getRoster().clear();
classroom.getRoster().addAll(newRoster);
```

---

**EXAMPLE** how to synchronize persistent set with a user required set:

```
/**
 * Assemble ClassroomUser relations.
 * @param classroom Classroom entity. Must be attached persistent or transient. Never null.
 * @param userIds Collection of user identifiers. Can be empty. Never null.
 */
private void assembleClassroomUsers(Classroom classroom, Collection<Integer> userIds) {
    // Make sure relation set exists (might be null for transient instance)
    if (classroom.getUsers() == null) {
        classroom.setUsers(new HashSet<ClassroomUser>());
    }
    // Create working copy of the collection
    Collection<Integer> ids = new HashSet<Integer>(userIds);
    // Check existing relations and retain or remove them as required
    Iterator<ClassroomUser> it = classroom.getUsers().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Integer userId = it.next().getUser().getId();
        if (!ids.remove(userId)) {
            it.remove(); // This will be picked by the deleteOrphans=true
        }
    }
    // Create new relations from the remaining set of identifiers
    for (Integer userId : ids) {
        ClassroomUser classroomUser = new ClassroomUser();
        classroomUser.setClassroom(classroom);
        // User must not have ClassroomUser relations initialized, otherwise Hibernate 
        // will get conflicting instructions what to persist and what to drop => error.
        // It might be safer to use dummy transient instance...
        User dummyUser = new User();
        dummyUser.setId(userId);
        classroomUser.setUser(dummyUser);
        classroom.getUsers().add(classroomUser);
    }
}
```

This approach might seem a little bit complex. You might be able to create something simpler (but probably not too much) with custom `equals`/`hashCode` and some `Set<E>` manipulation methods (e.g. from Guava).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but got the exception, "A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: com.myco.fdr.myproject.lms.classroom.model.classroom.roster"

Comment: That is because you probably didn't follow my instructions. You must not replace the collection. Can you confirm that you are getting the error even without changing the collection?

Comment: K, following your instructions (clear, and then addAll), I run into a new exception -- "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '7745AFA45C304375B6691CAA8C8480FA-STUDENT1' for key 'CLASSROOM_ROSTER_IDX_01'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '7745AFA45C304375B6691CAA8C8480FA-STUDENT1' for key 'CLASSROOM_ROSTER_IDX_01'".  If there was already a user in the list, it would appear "clear" doesn't cause any deletes to be issued.

Comment: That is probably the order in which Hibernate INSERTs new entries and DELETEs the old ones. I will update my answer with code snippet from one project, where I had to implement what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks very much for this code sample.  I want to make sure I'm implementing it correctly . YOu no longer have a call to ".clear()" anywhere?  If that's true, I think I'm following the logic, but now the orphan records remain, despite the fact I have verified through debugging the "it.remove()" method is getting called.

Comment: My approach is not using `clear()`, because in my case I didn't want to delete and re-create existing relations. If, in your case, the removed relations are not getting deleted, then there must be something else wrong with the code. Let's recap: you have `deleteOrphans=true`, you are doing the update within a transaction (i.e. `Classroom` is attached to an active session), you are not tampering with the `Set` instance itself (e.g. by replacing it with something else)... correct? If so, then I will probably need to see some code.